# What do the constructs `<DATA>`, `chomp` and `shift` do in this file reading function?

Tags: perl

I am using an existing function to read a file.

```
sub testRead {
    my $file = shift;
    open(DATA, "$file") || die "Can not open $file: $!";

    my $title = <DATA>;
    chomp($title);
    my @names = split(/\t/, $title);
    shift(@names);

    my @data = ();
    my $row = 0;
    while(<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @line = split(/\t/);
        for my $i (1 .. $#line) {
            $data[$i-1][$row] = $line[$i];
        }
        $row ++;
    }

    close DATA;
    return (\@data, \@names);
}
```

I can generally understand what does this function does, but I am not quite sure about `my $title = <DATA>;`. I know `<DATA>` represents the file handle, but what exactly does this line of code aim to do? Besides, what do `chomp($title);` and `shift(@names);` aim to do? Moreover, in the `while(<DATA>)` loop, there is single line of code `chomp;`, what does it do?

Comment: I count about 4 distinct questions there … most of which could be answered by looking up keywords in Perldoc.

Comment: Aside: The special filehandle `DATA` shouldn't be used to open a file, because it also refers to the `__DATA__` section embedded in the current file. But, there are a number of “unsafe” things in this script … that one, however, would easily look very mysterious and magical if anything were to “go wrong” and start reading from the source file instead of the filesystem :-D

Comment: place `local $_;` before the start of your `while` loop.  This is because `while (<FH>) {...}` will overwrite `$_` without properly localizing it.

Answer (score 6):

> But I am not quite sure about the following lines of code:
>
> ```
> my $title = <DATA>;
> ```
>
> I know represents the file handler, but what exactly does this line of code aim to do?

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators

> Besides, what do chomp($title); and shift(@names); aim to function?

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html

> Moreover, in the loop of while(", there is single line of code
>   "chomp;", what does it do?

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Answer (score 1):

The file-read operator is used in scalar context here.

```
my $title = <DATA>;
```

Reads one line from `DATA` into `$title`. The loop:

```
while (<DATA>) {
   ...
}
```

will run until the end of file is hit, storing the currently read line in `$_`.

`chomp` will trim the variable passed as its argument (it does *not* return the trimmed string), meaning it cuts off <strike>all whitespace</strike> a newline (or whatever is in `$/`) at the string's end.

As with most functions expecting a single argument, `$_` will be used if the function in question has been invoked without an argument (hence the lone `chomp` in the loop).

Next, the now trimmed string is split into an array using the tab character `\t` as token delimiters. Of the resulting array, the first is discarded using `shift`. Here's the script annotated:

```
my $title = <DATA>;
# $title is now: Foo\tBar\tZoid\n

chomp($title);
# $title is now: Foo\tBar\tZoid

my @names = split /\t/, $title;
# @names is now: "Foo", "Bar", "Zoid"

shift @names;
# @names is now: "Bar", "Zoid"
```

Comment: chomp does not behave even near to what you claim here. chomp will NOT "cut off all whitespace"! chomp will delete the value of $/ (normally newline) if it is at the end of the string, else it will do nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, @tad. I don't know *where* that came from. My answer is edited...

Answer (score 1):

```
my $title = <DATA>;
```

The DATA filehandle is a way of including file contents in the source code file (see perldata.pod).

Somewhere in you your code there is either __DATA__ or __END__ token, lines following
those tokens are returned each time you read from the DATA filehandle.

So, the above code reads the first line after the __DATA__ token and assigns it to $title.

```
chomp($title);
```

removes newline (if any) from the end of $title.

```
shift(@names);
```

removes the 1st element from @names, and then discards it.

chomp() with no arguments chomps $_ the same as if you wrote chomp($_)

Comment: The OP calls `open` on `DATA`, so in this case it has nothing to do with `__DATA__` and `__END__`.